# Boy joins creepy psychic co-op found family

Tags: story-identification, psychic

I read this at school 1970-80 in a library book. It was either a longish short story or just possibly the start of a book I didn't finish.

A boy is taken in/abducted by an old man who lives with a weird 'found' family, possibly on a ramshackle farm.

The old man is odd but I think benevolent. The family includes a pair of identical twins and a very old baby in a crib. There may be others. Together they form a psychically linked 'co-operative', all with their own psychic powers.

The twins are analogous to 'hands' and can teleport to fetch things. I distinctly remember them catching live blackbirds and eating them. The baby is the 'brain' of the group and very powerful. I think there was also a girl who spoke to the boy and 'removed' his need for the toilet.

I recall it as a creepy tale but more sci-fi/fantasy than horror. I didn't read horror that age.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is very likely to be Theodore Sturgeon's short story "[Baby Is Three](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56276)" (1952), or the fix-up novel that incorporates it, *[More Than Human](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1499)* (1953). See the answer for another question about this story by the venerable @user14111 at [People connected by telepathy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/185638/people-connected-by-telepathy/185639#185639).

As taken from the [short Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_Is_Three) about the story:

> The story describes the creation and "bleshing" of a new life form,
> Homo Gestalt, on Earth. It is formed by the symbiosis of four or more
> humans with paranormal abilities. One person, the "head" of the
> organism, assembles and directs the various parts through telepathy,
> **another is the "hands" of the organism**, able to move and change
> physical objects by telekinesis, the third and fourth persons are
> **twins** able to **teleport at will**, and the fifth person of the organism
> is a **silent baby** with Down syndrome with a brain like a computer and
> who acts as the "brain". "Bleshing" is how the organism describes its
> own completeness and functionality. The plot follows the psychiatric
> evaluation of a fifteen-year-old boy named Gerry, who believes he has
> murdered his caregiver Miss Kew for endangering the "bleshing" of his
> new organism.

The story can be [read online in the context of its original publication](https://archive.org/stream/galaxymagazine-1952-10/Galaxy_1952_10#page/n5/mode/2up), courtesy of the Internet Archive.

Comment: I've had a look at that story and  it does seem to be it. I don't think I read it all originally but the little black girl who kept saying "hee hee" I definitely remember. Thanks.